# 'sudo' command broken [3 incorrect attemps without giving a promt for pass] Debian 10

Tags: debian, sudo

i need your help very much. I  have debian 10 server with 2 users: root and user (added to sudo group). I use user account with RDP, and 'sudo' command always worked well.

The problem started when I tried to do (from user account):

```
$ echo 'deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian bookworm main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

There was some errors about libcrypt and I tried something like that (dont remember exactly):

```
$ sudo echo 'deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian bookworm main' >> sudo /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I think the problem, that I echoed something to 'sudo'? I`m no very familiar with linux, I googled few days, but I cant solve the problem.
Most command with sudo i receive this output instantly, without giving me a promt for password:

```
$ sudo whoami
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

If I try:

```
$ cat /etc/sudoers
cat: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

Every command with sudo access denied. I cant change config files, that I googled about.
So I only have access to user account through RDP, and if I try without sudo i receive:

```
$ apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Please help me to understand the problem and to fix it.

Comment: You may have locked yourself out of using `sudo`. What does `faillock` return?

Comment: Btw, all of the commands you tried without `sudo` are failing by design (root-only permissions).

Comment: ajgring619: $ faillock
bash: faillock: command not found

Comment: ajgring619: also I know my root password, but  i cant ssh or rdp to root account and something like - $ echo -n 'password' | sudo -S -k  --- gives error of 3 failed login attemps, like I describe in the post.

Comment: ssh to your user account, then run `su -` to get a root prompt.

Comment: there is new problem on the way: i cant ssh to server, only rdp session to user account. i checked ssh, its running and port 22 listening, but i still getting error 'ssh exchange identification: Read: connection reset by peer'. `$ systemctl status sshd

Comment: `$ systemctl status sshd
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-12-13 10:06:29 EST; 3 weeks 4 days ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 585 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4686)
   Memory: 10.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─585 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
` -

Comment: Can you open a terminal via the RDP session? If so, then `su -` from there.

Comment: if i try to restart the service i get - `systemctl restart sshd
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'ssh.service'.
Authenticating as: ,,, (user)
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to restart sshd.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status sshd.service' for details.

Comment: ajgringo619: yes, ican open terminal in rdp session. Usually I used terminator, and the problem happened in terminator, but now i cant open terminator terminal, only xfce terminal. i dodnt know if this info will help you to understand the problem

Comment: output is:`$ su -
su: Authentication failure
`

Comment: Are you using the root password when trying `su -`?

Comment: i`m instantly receive this output without receiving promt for password.

Comment: Ouch - this is becoming above my pay grade; hopefully someone who's more experienced can help you. I probably would have just reinstalled by now.

Comment: As a guess, this sounds like something is screwed up with PAM. Do you remember doing anything with that?

Comment: I cant reinstall, i dont have phisically access to server, i dont have backup, and i should use sudo to copy some important files.( I definitely did something with PAM (googled some answers) but i dodnt remember what exactly. I think maybe /etc/pam.d/common-auth

Comment: this config from user with nano looks like: 'auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure

auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so

auth    required                        pam_permit.so
'

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `bookworm` (= will be Debian 12 once it's released) repository to Debian 10 would have been a bad idea, since you can't skip over releases when upgrading: you must first upgrade to Debian 11 "bullseye" before going for "bookworm".

Fortunately your first attempt (without `sudo`) would have failed because `/etc/apt/sources.list` requires root access to write.

Your remembered version of the second command should not have caused any major problems either, assuming that you were not already root and in `/usr/bin` when executing it.

```
sudo echo 'deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian bookworm main' >> sudo /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This command actually means "use root privileges to write the text in single quotes to standard output, then (as a regular user) append it to a file named "sudo" in the current directory (creating the file if it doesn't exist). So this should not have caused any major harm either, unless your memory was wrong.

Without (successfully) using `sudo` or otherwise having root access, you won't be able to use `apt` or other package management commands, as those require root privileges to work.

I would suggest checking several things:

### What is the actual status of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Run `less /etc/apt/sources.list` to view it. You should be able to do it as a regular user without any special permissions.

### What did you *actually* do?

Use the `history` command to view the command history, instead of relying on your memory.

### What is happening now?

You could run `type sudo` to see what is actually being run when you use the `sudo` command. Normally it should respond with:

```
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo
```

or perhaps

```
sudo is hashed (/usr/bin/sudo)
```

If it tells you something different, you either have something non-standard named `sudo` in your $PATH before the `/usr/bin` directory, or you have managed to define a shell alias or function with the name `sudo` and it is getting executed instead of the real `sudo command`.

If that is the problem, you should be able to use the real `sudo` command by specifying it by full path, i.e. `/usr/bin/sudo` instead of just `sudo`.

---

It looks like you managed to add `bookworm` repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. If you also have `unattended-upgrades` package installed, the system may have begun attempting to upgrade itself from Debian 10 "buster" straight to "bookworm" (future Debian 12, still in testing phase), skipping over Debian 11... which is not going to work.

By trying to install `python3-dev`, `python3.10-dev`, `libpython3.10`, `libpython3.10-dev` and `python3.10` after adding `bookworm` repository you may also have caused a dependency cascade which triggered an upgrade of many (but not all) system libraries.

Effectively, you may have [made a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian): a freakish combination of packages from different releases that were never promised to work together.

`/var/log/dpkg.log` is a low-level package management log that should record all recent package management operations, whether manual or automatic. It should be readable by a regular user. Do you see anything recorded in there at about the time the problem started?

Each line should begin with a timestamp, followed by a word that describes the particular action. The interesting lines should have the action word as `install`, `upgrade`, `remove` and/or `purge`.

After the action word, there should be the package name, then old version (or `<none>` if not applicable) and a new version (or `<none>`).

If you take the lines with timestamps *after* adding the bookworm repository (check the modification time of `/etc/apt/sources.list`), these lines should tell you exactly which packages have been replaced, most likely with corresponding packages from `bookworm`.

Unfortunately, since you apparently have only RDP access to the system, gaining root access and downgrading the packages back to `buster`-appropriate versions might not be possible to you without help from someone who can access the bootloader of the system.

To recover, it might be necessary to boot the system to rescue mode from an external media, then activate network interfaces and `chroot` into the damaged system as root. Then it should be possible to downgrade the mis-upgraded packages, by reversing the install/update/remove actions listed in the `/var/log/dpkg.log` file at or after the point of you adding the `bookworm` repository.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer!

the status of sources.list is :
`deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian bookworm main`

Comment: ajgringo619 says that maybe it something with PAM, i found in history that i opened (and i think redacted)
this file - /etc/pam.d/sudo
the content of this file at the moment is:
`#%PAM-1.0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
`

Comment: there is a limit of chrachters, so i will try to show you the output with the pastebin - https://pastebin.com/LzFnLUrf

Comment: `type sudo` - give output `sudo is hashed (/usr/bin/sudo)`
`/usr/bin/sudo apt update
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
` - without giving password promt.

Comment: output of `/var/log/dpkg.log` is also huge, and unfortunately i dont understand a most part of it. If i understand correctly, iv managed to add bookworm to sources, maybe this is the main problem? Also, the output of `type sudo' is not exactly what it should be.Once again thank you for such a great answer and i hope you will be able help me to solve this problem from hell

Comment: if i try `sudo -u user -s
sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked?` - from the user rdp session. maybe it will help for someone to understand the problem

Comment: `sudo is hashed (/usr/bin/sudo)` looks OK, you just seem to have a slightly different shell than me. So the problem seems to be that you've had a partial upgrade from buster to bookworm, and library incompatibilities are preventing `sudo` and possibly other authentication libraries from working. The fact that you have only RDP access to the system is a major block from recovering from this. See my edit above.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! next time ill not be such a lamo.i dont have choice, i will try to backup available data and fully reinstall the system.